# Modify the graphical parts of the Android OS

Tags: linux-kernel, graphics, android

I’m going through the Android kernel and Google Glass kernel, and I’m trying to find the graphical parts of the operating system. I want to modify things like the splash screen displayed while the OS boots, how applications are displayed, etc. Where in the kernel can this be found and modified?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Android, which is not a Unix-like operating system, despite using the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent chance that the "graphical parts" you're after aren't in the kernel at all. Most of a regular Linux box's graphics stack is in user space, so I don't see why Android would be any different.

The only large piece of graphics code in the stock Linux kernel is the [Direct Rendering Manager](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DRM/), which is little more than an interface that lets user-space graphics code talk to the graphics hardware. The DRM is part of the [Direct Rendering Infrastructure](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/), which is largely user-space, as is everything that talks to it, such as the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), the [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), the [widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_(GUI)) toolkits, the [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) implementation, etc.

This design minimizes the amount of kernel code on purpose to reduce the security risks from having excess code in kernel space.

Comment: But If I'm flashing my phone with my own prebuilt Android Kernel from HTC. So there has to be a graphical part: Like desktop-screen and the applications. The question still remains, how can I flash my phone if there is no graphics?

Comment: @Arif: You seem to be confused about what a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) is. Click that link. All of the parts you mention in your comment about are outside the kernel. They're either part of Android's user-space, or they're user-space add-ons from other providers, such as HTC in your case. The OS image you're flashing to the phone contains a whole lot more than just the Linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Warren Young for making something more clear. I udnerstand that the kernel has nothing to do with the user Interface. Do you know how I can add a userinterface to kernel? And is there any tutorials for that?

Comment: @Arif: I suggest that you get involved with the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/), or one of its derivatives, such as [CyanogenMod](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/). Anyway, you're getting really off-topic for this site now. Developer discussions are better on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), and Android questions belong on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/). This site would be appropriate if you'd rooted your phone and wanted to know how to set up a cron script via ssh or something like that.